# Zend form element errors not display

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form, zend-form-element

I have a simple contact form.When I submit form error messages not display.Pls help me

```
class Users_Form_ContactForm extends Zend_Form{
    public function init(){
        $this->setName('contact');

        $user_name = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('name');
        $user_name->setLabel($this->getView()->translate('Ismingiz:'));
        $user_name->setRequired(true)
                ->addValidator('alnum')
                ->addFilter('StripTags')
                ->addFilter('StringTrim')
                ->setAttrib('class', 'input margin_top_10');

        $email_validate = new Zend_Validate_EmailAddress();
        $email_validate->setMessages(array(
                                          Zend_Validate_EmailAddress::INVALID => "1. Invalid type given, value should be a string",
                                          Zend_Validate_EmailAddress::INVALID_FORMAT => "2. '%value%' is no valid email address in the basic format local-part@hostname",
                                          Zend_Validate_EmailAddress::INVALID_HOSTNAME => "3. '%hostname%' is no valid hostname for email address '%value%'",
                                          Zend_Validate_EmailAddress::INVALID_MX_RECORD => "4. '%hostname%' does not appear to have a valid MX record for the email address '%value%'",
                                          Zend_Validate_EmailAddress::INVALID_SEGMENT => "5. '%hostname%' is not in a routable network segment. The email address '%value%' should not be resolved from public network.",
                                          Zend_Validate_EmailAddress::DOT_ATOM => "6. '%localPart%' can not be matched against dot-atom format",
                                          Zend_Validate_EmailAddress::QUOTED_STRING => "7. '%localPart%' can not be matched against quoted-string format",
                                          Zend_Validate_EmailAddress::INVALID_LOCAL_PART => "8. '%localPart%' is no valid local part for email address '%value%'",
                                          Zend_Validate_EmailAddress::LENGTH_EXCEEDED => "9. '%value%' exceeds the allowed length",
                                     ));

        $email = new Zend_Form_Element_Text("email");
        $email->setLabel($this->getView()->translate("Email manzilingiz:"))
                ->setRequired(true)
                ->addValidator($email_validate)
                ->addFilter('StringTrim')
                ->setAttrib('class', 'input margin_top_10')
                ->addFilter('StringToLower');

        $captcha = new Zend_Form_Element_Captcha('captcha', array(
                                                                 'captcha' => array(
                                                                     'captcha' => 'MyImage',
                                                                     'label' => $this->getView()->translate('Rasmdagi belgilarni kiriting'),
                                                                     'required' => true,
                                                                     'wordLen' => 5,
                                                                     'width' => 150,
                                                                     'height' => 40,
                                                                     'timeout' => 300,
                                                                     'fontSize' => 20,
                                                                     'gcFreq' => 5,
                                                                     'dotNoiseLevel' => 0,
                                                                     'lineNoiseLevel' => 0,
                                                                     'background' => 0,
                                                                     'font' => 'files/captcha/fonts/1.ttf',
                                                                     'imgDir' => 'files/captcha/image',
                                                                     'imgUrl' => '/files/captcha/image',
                                                                 )
                                                            ));
        $captcha->setIgnore(true);
        $captcha->setAttrib('class', 'input margin_top_10');

        $text = new Zend_Form_Element_Textarea("text");
        $text->setRequired(true)
                ->addFilter('StringTrim')
                ->setAttrib('class', 'input margin_top_10')
                ->addFilter('StringToLower')
                ->setLabel($this->getView()->translate("Xat matni:"))
                ->setAttrib('maxlength','200')
                ->setAttrib('style','height:100px;width:360px;');

        $button = new Zend_Form_Element_Submit('users_button');
        $button->setLabel($this->getView()->translate('Kiritish'))
                ->setAttrib('class', 'input margin_top_10');

        $this->addElements(array($user_name, $email, $text,$captcha, $button));
        $this->setMethod('post');
        $lang = $_SESSION['Poputchik']['slang'];
        $this->setAction(Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getBaseUrl() . '/' . $lang . '/default/category/contact');
        $language = $_SESSION['Poputchik']['language'];
        $translator = new Zend_Translate('array', APPLICATION_PATH.'/languages/errors/'.$language.'.php');
        $this->setTranslator($translator);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using "$yourForm->isValid($formdata)" method in your controller??

Comment: what does the error message say?

Comment: Do your form elements have the "Error" decorator on them? If not, add it and check again.

Comment: yes I use isValid() function in my controller

Comment: thanks for all Its working.I wrong use isValid() function.

Answer (score 4):

in your controller you should use something like

```
if($this->getRequest()->isPost()){
    if($form->isValid($this->getRequest()->getPost()){
        $values=$form->getValues();
        //do the stuff with (array) $values
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A primary use case for forms is validating submitted data.

If the submitted data is not valid, it has methods for retrieving the various error codes and messages for elements and sub forms.

To validate a full form, use the isValid() method in your controller action:

```
if (!$form->isValid($_POST)) {
// failed validation
}
```

give a look [here](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.form.forms.html)